# pytorch - model.named_parameters() returns 0 after optimizer.zero_grad() step

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to store the weights of the model. The code is given below:

```
for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
    outputs = model(**batch)
    loss = outputs.loss
    loss = loss / args.gradient_accumulation_steps
    accelerator.backward(loss)
    progress_bar.update(1)
    progress_bar.set_postfix(loss=round(loss.item(), 3))
    del outputs
    gc.collect()
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    
    if (step+1) % args.gradient_accumulation_steps == 0 or (step+1) == len(train_dataloader):
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
reference_gradient = [ p.grad.view(-1) if p.grad is not None else torch.zeros(p.numel()) for 
n, p in model.named_parameters()]
reference_gradient = torch.cat(reference_gradient)
```

However, reference_gradient tensor has all zeros in it. How can I save the gradients of the entire model?

Answer (score 0):

If you `zero_grad` the gradients - you delete the information. You cannot access the gradients after you set them to zero. You need to save the gradients before `optimizer.zero_grad()`.